# Executing a PHP script from within nested batch scripts

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, filezilla

I'm trying to rewrite our Windows FTP server configuration script that was created for IIS and now we're trying to get something similar working for Filezilla Server.

The structure goes like this, we have a batch file which is a for loop of another batch file, so we can batch configure our FTP websites.  This batch file I'm currently trying to get working contains a line of code to execute a PHP script to set up the FTP username and password in Filezilla as well as doing a few other neat things.

Now, running `CreateIIStmp.bat var1 var2` works just fine.  But executing the BatchCreateIIS.bat seems to skip the execution of the php script, or the php script fails.  (I'm just looking into how I put in some error handling into the PHP script to catch any error and display it, but I'm not a (PHP) developer/coder so I'll be updating this when I figure it out.)

Here's a stripped down version of what I'm talking about:

The initial batch file BatchCreateIIS.bat:

```
@Echo off

for /f %%X in (NewWebsiteEntries.txt) do start cmd.exe /c "CreateIIStmp.bat %%X %%X"

echo ...
echo *** BATCH PROCESS HAS BEEN COMPLETED ***
pause
```

The CreateIIStmp.bat:

```
@ echo off
C:\php5\php-win.exe -f filezilla-user-script.php -- %1 %2
pause
@echo on
```

The NewWebsiteEntries.txt:

```
somedomain.com ftpuname
somedomain2.net ftpuname2
```

The filezilla-user-script.php:

```
<?php

$xmlfolder = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/FileZilla Server/';
$xmlfilename = 'FileZilla Server.xml';

$ftpRoot = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/';
$ftpDocumentation = 'C:/Documentation ftp server/';

$xmlfile = $xmlfolder . $xmlfilename;
$xmlbackupfile = $xmlfolder . @date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '_FileZilla_Server.xml';


// Copy Config for backup
createXMLbackup($xmlfile,$xmlbackupfile);



//Load XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);

$msg = "Allowed usernames: 20 characters out of a...z A...Z 0...9 _ \n\nPlease input username (Ctrl+C to quit)";

// Copy Config for backup before each change, too.
createXMLbackup($xmlfile,$xmlbackupfile);

    echo "\n\n";
    $input = ($argv[2]);
    echo "\n";
//echo 'Userinput: ' . $input . "\n";
    $isvalid = isUserID($input);
//var_dump($isvalid);

    if($isvalid)
    {

        $ftpUserFolder = $ftpRoot . ($argv[1]);

        if ((file_exists($ftpUserFolder) && is_dir($ftpUserFolder)))
        {
            echo "The directory $ftpUserFolder exists.\nPlease select another user name.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            //echo "The directory $ftpUserFolder does not exist\n";

            if(!check_user_exists($xml,$input))

            {
                echo "Adding user $input...\n";

                if (!mkdir($ftpUserFolder))
                {
                    die("Could not create directory $ftpUserFolder \n");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Directory $ftpUserFolder created.\n";
                }

                $password = generatePassword();
                //echo 'Password: ' . $password . "\n";

                $user = $xml->Users->addChild('User');
                $user->addAttribute('Name', $input);

                $option = $user->addChild('Option', md5($password));
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'Pass');

                $option = $user->addChild('Option');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'Group');

                $option = $user->addChild('Option', '0');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'Bypass server userlimit');

                $option = $user->addChild('Option', '0');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'User Limit');

                $option = $user->addChild('Option', '0');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'IP Limit');

                $option = $user->addChild('Option', '1');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'Enabled');

                $option = $user->addChild('Option', 'none');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'Comments');

                $option = $user->addChild('Option', '0');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'ForceSsl');

                $filter = $user->addChild('IpFilter');
                $filter->addChild('Disallowed');
                $filter->addChild('Allowed');

                $permissions = $user->addChild('Permissions');
                $permission = $permissions->addChild('Permission');

                $permission->addAttribute('Dir', str_replace("/","\\",$ftpUserFolder));

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '1');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'FileRead');

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '1');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'FileWrite');

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '0');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'FileDelete');

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '1');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'FileAppend');

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '1');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'DirCreate');

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '0');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'DirDelete');

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '1');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'DirList');

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '1');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'DirSubdirs');

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '1');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'IsHome');

                $option =  $permission->addChild('Option', '0');
                $option->addAttribute('Name', 'AutoCreate');

                $speed = $user->addChild('SpeedLimits');
            $speed->addAttribute('DlType', '1');
            $speed->addAttribute('DlLimit', '10');
            $speed->addAttribute('ServerDlLimitBypass', '0');
            $speed->addAttribute('UlType', '1');
            $speed->addAttribute('UlLimit', '10');
                $speed->addAttribute('ServerUlLimitBypass', '0');
                $speed->addChild('Download');
                $speed->addChild('Upload');

                $rv = $xml->asXML($xmlfile);
                //echo $rv . "\n";
                if(!$rv)
                {
                    die('SimpleXML could not write file');
                }


//$newentry = $xml->addChild('element', iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $write));
//The DOM extension uses UTF-8 encoding. Use utf8_encode() and utf8_decode()
//to work with texts in ISO-8859-1 encoding or Iconv for other encodings.
//make human readable, parse using DOM function
//otherwise everything will be printed on one line

                if( !file_exists($xmlfile) ) die('Missing file: ' . $xmlfile);
                else
                {
                    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","ISO-8859-1");
                    //Setze die Flags direkt nach dem Initialisieren des Objektes:
                    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
                    $dom->formatOutput = true;

                    //$dl = @$dom->load($xmlfile); // remove error control operator (@) to print any error message generated while loading.
                    $dl = $dom->load($xmlfile); // remove error control operator (@) to print any error message generated while loading.
                    if ( !$dl ) die('Error while parsing the document: ' . $xmlfile);
                    //echo $dom->save($xmlfile) . "\n";
                    if(!$dom->save($xmlfile))
                    {
                        die('DOMDocument could not write file');
                    }
                }

//Create documentation

                $docuFile = $ftpDocumentation . $input . '.txt';
                //echo $docuFile . "\n";

                $docuString = "Username: " . $input . "\n";
                $docuString = $docuString . "Password: " . $password . "\n";
                $docuString = $docuString . "Folder: " . str_replace("/","\\",$ftpUserFolder) . "\n";
                $docuString = $docuString . "Date: " . @date("d.m.Y") . "\n";
                // $docuString = $docuString . "\n";
                // $docuString = $docuString . "Direct link:\n";
                // $docuString = $docuString . "ftp://" . $input . ":" . $password . "@ftp.yourcompany.com";




                $handleDocuFile = fopen($docuFile, "wt");
                if(!$handleDocuFile)
                {
                    die('Could not fopen docu file');
                }

                $rv = fwrite($handleDocuFile, $docuString);
                if(!$rv)
                {
                    die('Could not fwrite docu file');
                }

                // Close xml file
                $rv = fclose($handleDocuFile);
                if(!$rv)
                {
                    die('Could not fclose docu file');
                }
                echo "Documentary file written.\n";

                $ftpExecutable = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FileZilla Server\\FileZilla server.exe\" /reload-config";

                $command = $ftpExecutable;

                $last_line = system($command, $retval);

                echo ("Filezilla reloaded, user active.\n");

                echo ("Close Notepad to add another user or quit.\n");

                $command = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe $docuFile";
                $last_line = system($command, $retval);

            }
            else
            {
                echo "Username $input already exists...\n";

            }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username $input is invalid\n";
    }



function check_user_exists($xml,$username)
{
    $children=$xml->Users->children();

    foreach($children as $child)
    {
        if ($child->getName()=='User')
        {

            foreach($child->attributes() as $attributes )
            {
                if(trim($attributes) == trim($username))
                {
                    echo "Username $username already exists... \n";
                    return true;
                }

            }

        }


    }

    return false;
}




function isUserID($username)
{
    //return preg_match('/^\w{2,20}$/', $username);
    return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/', $username);
}

function isValid($str)
{
    //return !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9.#\\-$]/', $str);
    return !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\_\-]/', $str);
}


function getInput($msg)
{
    fwrite(STDOUT, "$msg: ");
    $varin = trim(fgets(STDIN,20));
    return $varin;

    //$input = fgets($fr,128);        // read a maximum of 128 characters
}

function createXMLbackup($xmlfile,$xmlbackupfile)
{
    // Copy Config for backup
    $rv = copy($xmlfile,$xmlbackupfile);
    if(!$rv) 
    {
        die('Problem creating xml backup file');
    }
    echo "\nBackup file created\n";
}


function generatePassword ($length = 15)
{

    // start with a blank password
    $password = "";

    $possible = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    // we refer to the length of $possible a few times, so let's grab it now
    $maxlength = strlen($possible);

    // check for length overflow and truncate if necessary
    if ($length > $maxlength)
    {
        $length = $maxlength;
    }

    // set up a counter for how many characters are in the password so far
    $i = 0;

    // add random characters to $password until $length is reached
    while ($i < $length)
    {

        // pick a random character from the possible ones
        $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, $maxlength-1), 1);

        // have we already used this character in $password?
        if (!strstr($password, $char))
        {
            // no, so it's OK to add it onto the end of whatever we've already got...
            $password .= $char;
            // ... and increase the counter by one
            $i++;
        }

    }

    // done!
    return $password;

}
?>
```

I've looked around and there are some places that suggest using @ in front of calling in PHP so: `@C:\php5\php-win.exe -f filezilla-user-script.php -- %1 %2` but that doesn't work, and I can see that my script does work, just not in this nested form.

Maybe there's an approach to this problem that I'm missing?  Or something that I don't know about executing scripts in nested batch scripts?

Answer (score 0):

In your BatchCreateIIS.bat, when you use this:

```
start cmd.exe /c "CreateIIStmp.bat %%X %%X"
```

the parent cmd.exe will not wait for each instance of CreateIIStmp.bat (and child processes) to finish. Since you seem to be writing to the same XML file, it is likely that the DOM that get written last persists. Instead try this:

```
call "CreateIIStmp.bat %%X %%X"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, eventually, I bought a licence to CoreFTP server and we do this manually now.

Not great as a time efficient solution, but it works for us and this is in support of a legacy system that shall soon be shutdown in terms of ongoing production, for which I was setting this up.